# Json schema for either A or B

Tags: jsonschema

I want to write a schema specification which allows for either property A or B. For example, both of

```json
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "A" : "something"
}
```

```json
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "B" : "something else"
}
```

should be legal, but

```json
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "A" : "something",
  "B" : "something else"
}
```

should be illegal. What's the right way to do that with `2020-12/schema`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible with the `oneOf` operator. You can keep your property definitions outside of the oneOf, so you don't have to repeat yourself:

```
"type": "object",
"oneOf": [
  { "required": [ "A" ] },
  { "required": [ "B" ] }
],
"properties": {
  "A": { ... },
  "B": { ... },
  "foo": { ... }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize I can use "oneOf" on the same level as `properties`